# What does bearingTo(Location dest) exactly calculate?

Tags: android

What does `bearingTo(Location dest)` exactly calculate? Can anyone please explain this??

Thanks in advance.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DestinationLoc.setLatitude(39.543394);
    DestinationLoc.setLongitude(-119.816010);
    LocationManager lm =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Startloc.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
      Startloc.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude());
    if ( Startloc == null ) return;

    float azimuth = event.values[0];
    float baseAzimuth = azimuth;
    mInitialPosition.setText("Initial LatLong: " + Startloc.getLatitude() + " " + Startloc.getLongitude());
    GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField( Double
            .valueOf( Startloc.getLatitude() ).floatValue(), Double
            .valueOf( Startloc.getLongitude() ).floatValue(),
            Double.valueOf( Startloc.getAltitude() ).floatValue(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() );
    azimuth += geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north

    //Correct the azimuth
    azimuth = azimuth % 360;

    //This is where we choose to point it
    float direction = azimuth + Startloc.bearingTo( DestinationLoc );
    float direction2 = Startloc.bearingTo(DestinationLoc);
```

}

The `direction2` value is shown as negative.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of it?

Comment: yes. it says this. Returns the approximate initial bearing in degrees East of true North when traveling along the shortest path between this location and the given location. I am getting negative values for some lat long values. So i would like to know what is the exact calculation that is happening here

Comment: Show us your code along with input values

Comment: If your value is negative just keep adding 360 until it ends up in the range of angles you are used to thinking of directions in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo(android.location.Location)) please. It describes exactly that that method returns.

> Returns the approximate initial bearing in degrees East of true North
>   when traveling along the shortest path between this location and the
>   given location. The shortest path is defined using the WGS84
>   ellipsoid. Locations that are (nearly) antipodal may produce
>   meaningless results.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *dest*    the destination location
>
> **Returns**
>
> the initial bearing in degrees

Comment: what is WGS84 ellisoid?

Answer (score 4):

Source : [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)
Bearing is basically another ATTRIBUTE that is associated with Location object in Android. So, Location has lat, long and it can bearing, altitude, velocity. According to the method description [getBearing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing())  it means the horizontal direction of the device.

Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation))

In land navigation, a bearing is ordinarily calculated in a clockwise direction starting from a reference direction of 0° and increasing to 359.9 degrees.[4] Measured in this way, a bearing is referred to as an azimuth by the US Army but not by armies in other English speaking nations, which use the term bearing.[5] If the reference direction is north (either true north, magnetic north, or grid north), the bearing is termed an absolute bearing. In a contemporary land navigation context, true, magnetic, and grid bearings are always measured in this way, with true north, magnetic north, or grid north being 0° in a 360-degree system.[4]